# I can't seem to get rid of the "Welcome to nginx" page for reverse proxy

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am using nginx on Ubuntu 18 for a reverse proxy and HTTPS tunnel to those localhost services. Here's my site config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name my.domain.com;

    # add Strict-Transport-Security to prevent man in the middle attacks
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;

    location /service1 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8989;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/my.domain.com;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    # Other certbot stuff for signed HTTPS certificate
}
```

Basically when I go to `https://my.domain.com`, I don't want anything to show. I want it to be an error, as if the page doesn't exist. Right now it shows me "Welcome to nginx!". I have Googled ways of getting rid of it but I have had no luck. I completely disabled `default` under `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

I only want nginx to serve `https://my.domain.com/service1` and redirect HTTP to HTTPS, but I do not want any welcome pages to be served.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work, near the existing location blocks.

```
// New part starts
location / {
     return 418;
}
// New part ends

location /service1 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8989;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```